# Sometimes Windows 7 NAS cannot be mounted

Tags: mount, automount, file-sharing, nas

I can successfully connect my Xubuntu PC (cable-connected to office network) to a Windows NAS using this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//Hall/Share /media/HallShare cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

And running:

```
sudo mount -a
```

The mount is automatic on boot.

The problem is that **often (but not always)** when I turn on my PC, NAS is not mounted (that is `/media/HallShare` is empty and `sudo mount -l` doesn't list anything related to this folder). And when I try to manually run `sudo mount -a`, the command hangs with no messages for indefinite time:

```
lorenzo@PC:~$ sudo mount -v -a
mount: proc già montato su /proc
mount: UUID=3c72b8d3-a568-46bd-9fa0-1fa59532b579 già montato su /home
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.112,unc=\\Hall\Share,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,ver=1,user=lorenzo-1,pass=********
```

I cannot find anything in `/var/log/dmsg`. Can somebody help me to identify the problem?

---

Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

# Windows NAS (\\hall)
//Hall/Share /media/HallShare cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,noauto,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

And my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
mount /media/HallShare
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NAS is being mounted with the `auto` option. This is known to cause problems on some system setups. You could fix this issue by adding the `noauto` option to your mount options:

`//Hall/Share /media/HallShare cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,noauto,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

However, this way your NAS will be mounted but not bound at boot at all, so you'll have to take another step: in a terminal type

`gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

At the end of the file, add the following line **before the exit 0** (if not there, be sure to add `exit 0` at the very end):

`sleep 20`

`mount /media/HallShare`

Save the file, reboot and you should be all set!
Good luck!

(For reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Comment: BTW: the command of choice in your case would be `sudo mount /media/HallShare` instead of `mount -a` accordingly.

Comment: Another note on the matter: Depending on whether you're using DHCP or fixed IPs, using a fixed IP-adress for your NAS and adding it to your /etc/fstab configuration instead of the resolved name might do the trick as well.

Comment: Thank you @FuzziQ. I edit these files and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: @FuzziQ Back to work from holydays. Unfortunately it does not work. I placed the `noauto` option and then done mounting in `/etc/rc.local`: sometimes it mounts, sometimes does not :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Please post the contents of your /etc/fstab and your /etc/rc.local.

Comment: I updated my question adding the content of files you asked.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm out of guesses. With those settings, it *should* work. My mount options are: noauto,nobrl,uid=fuzzyq,gid=users,credentials=/home/fuzzyq/.smbcredentials. Perhaps this works better for you, but I doubt it. Perhaps this issue is not a mounting problem at all.

Comment: Alright, I think I found another clue: please try to add **sleep 20** before the mount commands in your /etc/rc.local file. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, now I'm quite sure it's working every time. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it's working, congratulations!